# How best to store user credentials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, ember.js

I have previously used a session variable, i.e `session[:user_id]` to keep track of the current user, but I'm now trying to make my app work with EmberJS necessitating a Grape API backend instead of controllers and such. I was wondering, what is the best way to keep track of user credentials across pages: Session, Cookie, or Thread? I'm leaning toward Thread at the moment, but I was wondering what the pros and cons of each are?

Comment: It might depend on your api backend infrastructure but if you can start simple - why not use a cookie as you did in the past? works without having to "store" anything special / browser apps have worked this way for years without much pain

Comment: @ToranBillups that's definitely a possibility, but wouldn't there be a security risk in passing around a private token in an API driven app?

Comment: @onetwopunch i guess is no more risky then passing cookie around for a  normal app. i say if the token is a key of sort and you can expire it on the server side should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Authentication in API's is a little different. The user should be authorized on every request by passing some type of token rather than once per session.

Typically, you'll have a route that accepts username/password that will return an auth token and then the token will be passed as part of BasicAuth or in headers on every request. In Grape, there are a few ways to do this. You can add an Authentication helper:

```
module ApiHelpers
  module Authentication

    def authenticate!
      error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
    end

    def current_user
      if token_from_headers
        @current_user ||= User.find_by api_key: token_from_headers[1]
      end
    end

    def authenticate!
      error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
    end

    def token_from_headers
      /Token token="(.+)"/.match(headers['Authorization'])
    end
  end
end
```

Include that in the main api file:

```
class API < Grape::API
  helpers ApiHelpers::Authentication
end
```

Then, for every request that needs authentication:

```
resource :items do
  get do
    authenticate!
    present current_user.items, with: Entities::Item
  end
end
```

You can also add a custom middleware for authentication or authenticate using basic auth. More info on that in Grape's README: https://github.com/intridea/grape#authentication

I'm assuming your endpoint is using SSL?